# how to convert french charcaters into English charcaters in java script

Tags: javascript, regex

Here i have a  french and equal english characters.

French :` Ë À Ì Â Í Ã Î Ä Ï Ç Ò È Ó É Ô Ê Õ Ö ê Ù ë Ú î Û ï Ü ô Ý õ â û ã ÿ ç

English :' E A I A I A I A I C O E O E O E O O e U e U i U i U o Yo a u a y c

I did below function on my javascript.quiz_text is a textarea.

This function replaced french vowel charcaters only.And also some of the french vowel charactes(Ã) didnt replaced as a english characters.I have to convert those mentioned french characters.

Can anyone help me to covert those french characters into english on javascript ?

```
function checkgsm(){

    var quiz_text =document.getElementById('quiz_text');

    var s= quiz_text.value;


    var rExps=[ /[\xC0-\xC2]/g, /[\xE0-\xE2]/g,
    /[\xC8-\xCA]/g, /[\xE8-\xEB]/g,
    /[\xCC-\xCE]/g, /[\xEC-\xEE]/g,
    /[\xD2-\xD4]/g, /[\xF2-\xF4]/g,
    /[\xD9-\xDB]/g, /[\xF9-\xFB]/g ];

    var repChar=['A','a','E','e','I','i','O','o','U','u'];

    for(var i=0; i<rExps.length; i++)
    s=s.replace(rExps[i],repChar[i]);

    return s;
}
```

Comment: You just did not encompass all characters in your regexp. Look at character map carefully.

Comment: I knew the formats for vowels only which i mentioned in rExps variable.Dont know about other character's format.Could you send me the complete format ?

Comment: `charmap` is available on both limux and windows. If you have a Mac, ask their support ;-)

Comment: These characters aren't "French". They're *diacritics*. `Ö` or `ã` aren't part of the French alphabet. Why do you keep reverting my edits?

Comment: Ý, õ aren't French either

Answer (score 2):

You can use `iconv` function:

```
$this->_data = iconv("utf-8","ascii//TRANSLIT", JRequest::get('post'));
```

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, do what antyrat said, but if you want more control, you might want to use preg_replace:

```
$search = array('X1', 'X2', 'X3');
$replace = array('Y2', 'Y2', 'Y3');

$string = "X1X3X2";

echo str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

Would print:

```
Y1Y3Y2
```

Comment: `preg_replace` would complain about delimiters in your example. Or did you mean `strtr()`?

Comment: Sorry, I did mean str_replace. My fault entirely, thanks for pointing that out, I just adjusted it.